# Black screen during installation on a Dell Latitude E6510

Tags: 11.10, dell

I have download 32 and 64 bit version of Ubuntu 11.10 (latest) and tried to install/live run on my DELL Latitude E6510. But I just get black screen, even when I select "try" I can here login sound but not view. Here is specifications of laptop:

- Latitude E65100
- Intel Core i5
- 4096MB RAM
- NVIDIA NVS 3100M (Integrated RAMDC)

Comment: I posted the issue here: http://ubuntuforums.org/search.php?searchid=83867463. No Feedback yet.
I really get desperate and hope somebody knows how to help me!

Comment: @kodiakz this link doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem on a Dell E6510 by disabling the nouveau kernel driver with grub.  Use nouveau.modeset=0 kernel parameter as described at http://drivers.downloadatoz.com/tutorial/21775,fix-dell-latitude-e6410-black-screen-during-ubuntu-10-04-installation.html

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same problem on my machine, but I figured out that if you select F6 ->> then "x" mark the `noraid` and `nomodeset` it will boot and install, but the problem starts after the install completes. I still get the same black screen again. I am not a linux user but I think it has something to do with Graphics Adapter.

Answer (score 0):

I have exaclty the same machine and do not have problems with a complete fresh install, but after upgrading all packages and rebooting, the X-session does not start. The screen stays black and flickers. I did not figure out yet what upgrade acutally caused this.

Comment: I think/and probably this is video driver problem
Please, tell me how did you installed: from USB or CD, and what is your RAM?